# My 2TB Hard drive stopped showing up

Tags: usb, hard-drive, 22.04

I have checked `lsusb`, `sudo fdisk -i`, and eventually even my boot menu. No matter what it does not show up. I can hear the drive's fan working so I know it is receiving power, and the USB port is working fine. Any ideas what I could do?

Comment: I'm suspecting that either it is something wrong with the controller or the driver. Try to check both.(I'm assuming you know some Linux basics)

Comment: Indeed, if it does not show up in any of these commands, expect a hardware issue. Might be the drive, but could be the cable also.

Comment: Did it work before from USB port? Does it only get power from USB or has separate power supply? My SATA to USB adapter with only USB power worked great for a SSD, but did not have enough power for HDD.

Comment: I tried with a different cable and it was the same result. I have also had this hard drive working with this laptop using this USB port before. The only change since it last worked was a system update. If there are any screenshots/logs I can/should add, please ask.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be an issue with the board that converted the SATA port on the drive to USB. I ripped out the drive and got myself a SATA to USB card and it works like a charm